# RISC vs CISC stack

Tags: stack, processor

Here is a quote from the book "Introduction to Assembly language" about RISC (vs CISC)

> In MIPS, we could write procedures without using the stack. For most
>   normal procedures, we do not have to use the stack. The availability
>   of a large number of registers allows us to use register-based
>   parameter passing. However, when we write recursive procedures, we
>   have to use the stack.

I am very confused about the magic with working without the stack.
Any standard program has a chain calls: Main()-> Function1() -> Function2() -> ... ->

Even with lots of registers (128) the way is usual:

1. decide which registers you should take and save their context
   (usually pushing on the stack)
2. provide operations
3. return registers states (usually popping from the stack)

Nobody stops us to use register-based parameter passing in CISC, especially on modern processors.
So, how is it possible to do a program con RISC without the stack?

Comment: The quote you provided only mentions procedures writing procedures without using the stack, not whole programs. But if your program is simple enough, you are writing in assembly and you have enough registers then you could manually allocate a register to each variable and parameter. You'd probably still end up using the stack for the return address of any jsrs/calls/isrs etc though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what they're referring to is argument passing.  In most RISC machines, arguments are passed in registers and there are generally about 6-8 registers reserved for this purpose (and one for the return value). This isn't mandated, it's simply convention (and is called ABI or application binary interface).  So, if there are fewer arguments to the function than registers and those arguments are simple enough to fit in a register, you don't need extra stack space to pass those arguments.  On CISC machines, there aren't so many registers for arguments, so the ABI specifies that those arguments are passed on the stack.

Also, in RISC machines, there are many temporary registers available (specifically the callee save ones) for storing local variables.  On CISC machines, local variables are generally allocated on the stack and registers are generally reserved for intermediate values.

Answer (score 2):

A reduced instruction set computer (RISC  /pronounce as ˈrisk’/) is a computer which only use simple instructions  that can be divide into multiple instructions which perform low-level  operation within single clock cycle, as its name suggest.
Let we take an example of multiplying two number
                       A = A * B; <<<======this is C statement.
For this  particular task, a CISC processor would come prepared with a specific  instruction (we’ll call it “MULT”). When executed, this instruction
Loads the two values into separate registers
Multiplies the operands in the execution unit
And finally third, stores the product in the appropriate register.
Thus, the entire task of multiplying two numbers can be completed with one instruction:
MULT A,B <<<======this is assembly statement

```
   MULT is what is known as a “complex instruction.” It operates directly  on the computer’s memory banks and does not require the programmer to  explicitly call any loading or storing functions.
```

RISC processors only use simple instructions that can be executed within one clock cycle.
 In order  to perform the exact series of steps described in the CISC approach, a  programmer would need to code four lines of assembly:
            LOAD R1, A          <<<======this is assembly statement
            LOAD R2,B          <<<======this is assembly statement
            PROD A, B           <<<======this is assembly statement
            STORE R3, A       <<<======this is assembly statement
Advantage:-
Each instruction requires only one  clock cycle to execute, the entire program will execute in approximately  the same amount of time as the multi-cycle “MULT” command.
These RISC “reduced instructions”  require less transistors of hardware space than the complex  instructions, leaving more room for general purpose registers. Because  all of the instructions execute in a uniform amount of time (i.e. one  clock).
      **To know more about RISC and CISC , please follow the following link : -        **

http://www.firmcodes.com/difference-risc-sics-architecture/

Comment: How is - using less transistor then more GPR related?

Answer (score -1):

RISC

1. NO of instruction are less
2. Length of instruction is fixed
3. It uses load/ store instruction.
4. Example : ARM7, ARM9.
5. No of cycle required to execute a program are more 
   for example if we want to product 2 no then we use following code
   Load a, 12
   load b, 14,
   prod a, b
   store (memory location), b

CISC:

1. NO of instruction are more
2. Length of instruction is variable
3. It not uses load/ store instruction to access the memory
4. Example : Pentium
5. No of cycle required to execute a program are less
   for example 
   for product of two no use only
   MULT (memory location 1), memory location2
   and the result store at memory location 1

Comment: -1: doesn't answer the question. Besides, you're wrong about instruction cycles. Many processors can execute multiple instructions at once.